# Is it possible to decode a SPAMCAUSE field in a mail header?

Tags: decode, email-headers, email-spam

I'd like to decode this string:

```
X-OVH-SPAMCAUSE: gggruggvucftvghtrhhoucdtuddrfeelgedrvdduucetufdoteggodetrfdotffvucfrrhhofhhilhgvmecuqfggjfenuceurghilhhouhhtmecufedttdenucgohfhorhgsihguuggvnhfjughrucdlhedttddm
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 10):

I improved the given Python solutions by [Ikraider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41507130/is-it-possible-to-decode-a-spamcause-field-in-a-mail-header/62378426#62378426) and [DoubleYou](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41507130/is-it-possible-to-decode-a-spamcause-field-in-a-mail-header/68940045#68940045) and added a JavaScript solution, too.

Python:

```py
def Decode(msg):
    return ''.join([chr(ord(msg[i * 2]) + ord(msg[i * 2 + 1]) - 1768 + ord(msg[i * 2 + 1 - (i & 1)]) * 16) for i in range(len(msg) // 2)])

print(Decode('gggruggvucftvghtrhho'))
```

JavaScript:

```js
function Decode(msg)
{
    return Array(msg.length >> 1).fill(0).map((_, i) => String.fromCharCode(msg[i * 2].charCodeAt(0) + msg[i * 2 + 1].charCodeAt(0) - 1768 + (msg[i * 2 + 1 - (i & 1)].charCodeAt(0) << 4))).join('');
}

console.log(Decode('gggruggvucftvghtrhho'));
```

Comment: Precious ! And for lazy people, a quick fiddle to test your data online - https://jsfiddle.net/rfgb3qme/2/

Comment: Short and works great. Nice.

Answer (score 8):

There is a [Tor](https://www.torproject.org/) hidden service you can use to decode the tag located at http://6jbnmws2zq2m2fsfmpwnssgsrxovohgggphymkd4df2pgcw7ccrdy6ad.onion

According to it, the X-OVH-SPAMCAUSE you gave translates to this:

```
Vade Retro 01.394.21 AS+AV+AP+RT Profile: OVH; Bailout: 300; ^ForbiddenHdr (500)
```

Comment: It's definitely not a _good_ answer, because admitting to having reverse engineered the cipher they use would get me in trouble assuming I did that ; but he asked for a tool to decipher it and the tor hidden service I pointed to works for that. (I guess an appropriate answer would be "there is no legal way to do that")

Comment: @Asmadeus What is illegal about the Tor hidden service? Tor nodes are not inherently illegal (at least not in the United States).

Comment: @TylerH nothing wrong with having a tor service; but the original site that did it (=provide a decryption service) got taken down by vadesecure. Anyway that doesn't seem to have stopped others to post similar code publicly -- and it doesn't look like vadesecure took the bait yet, so it's probably going to stay public at this point :)

Answer (score 4):

Starting from [lkraider's great Python answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62378426), I improved the accuracy. It turns out that the offset characters (`c`..`g`) are alternately appended and prepended. So instead of just checking if one of them is in the pair, it is necessary to differentiate between, e.g., `fh` and `hf`, by keeping track of even or odd pairs.

```py
def decode(msg):
    text = ""
    for i in range(0, len(msg), 2):
        # add position as extra parameter
        text += unrot(msg[i: i + 2], i // 2)
    return text


def unrot(pair, pos, key=ord('x')):
    # "even" position => 2nd char is offset
    if pos % 2 == 0:
        # swap letters in pair
        pair = pair[1] + pair[0]
    # treat 1st char as offset
    offset = (ord('g') - ord(pair[0])) * 16
    # map to original character
    return chr(sum(ord(c) for c in pair) - key - offset)

print(decode('gggruggvucftvghtrhho'))
```

https://gist.github.com/DoubleYouEl/e3de97293ce3d5452b3be7a336a06ad7

Comment: Tested on many sources of Spamcause fields with success.

Answer (score 2):

Looks to be some obfuscation by rotating chars. I made an attempt at it using Python. It's not perfect but mostly seems to work:

```py
def decode(msg):
    text = []
    for i in range(0, len(msg), 2):
        text.append(unrot(msg[i: i + 2]))
    return str.join('', text)


def unrot(pair, key=ord('x')):
    offset = 0
    for c in 'cdefgh':
        if c in pair:
            offset = (ord('g') - ord(c)) * 16
            break
    return chr(sum(ord(c) for c in pair) - key - offset)


print(decode('gggruggvucftvghtrhho'))
```

https://gist.github.com/lkraider/9530798a695586fc1580d0728966f6f0